# Set workflow Laravel cookie in a SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, axios

Can someone please give me the workflow again. I would like my Laravel backend to set a cookie on the client the first time a SPA is requested. I have already tried something.

**SomeController**

```
        return response()->json([])->cookie(
            'cart_token', '123abc', 60
        );
```

When I test it with Postman or Insomnia, it works. But an Axios get request unfortunately does not. What am I missing?

Comment: If you're in an `http` environment and using chrome/safari, you cannot set cookies insecurely any longer.

Comment: Yes, is set in den session.php 'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false), to false to avoid that.

Comment: You can't use insecure cookies with chrome/safari in an http environment. Are you using `http://localhost` or `https://localhost` the **s** in the schema is important.

Comment: ok. thx for the information. i using http enviroment and firefox.